# Handle storing of child elements with same name and different XPath?

Tags: ruby, xpath, nokogiri

I'm trying to extract values from XML with Nokogiri.

I want to store, separated in an array, the child elements with the same name but different xpath. Those elements are `ProdA`, `ProdB`.

Currently I'm only trying to print the child elements, but the code I have so far  prints only "SDocument" and not the child elements.

The goal is have an array like this:

```
array = [["2","8"], ["8","9"]]
```

This is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(File.open("input.xml"))

a = doc.xpath("//SDocument").each do |n|
  n if n.text?
end

puts a
```

This is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Document-St-5>
  <SDocument>
    <ItemList>
      <Items_A>
        <ItemElem>
          <Item_Values>
            <ProdA>2</ProdA>
            <ProdB>8</ProdB>
          </Item_Values>
        </ItemElem>        
      </Items_A>
      <Items_B>
        <ItemElem>
          <Item_Values>
            <ProdA>8</ProdA>
            <ProdB>9</ProdB>
          </Item_Values>
        </ItemElem>
      </Items_B>
    </ItemList>
  </SDocument>
</Document-St-5>
```

Can somebody point me to the correct way please?

---

Update:

What I actually want is to store, in an array, the XPath of all unique child elements of `SDocument` node and those that have multiple 
occurences, store them grouped. But if possible get the XPath without knowing the name of the children, only get unique XPaths.

For example:

The child elements `StName` and `StCode` only have one occurence each one, then the array that has the XPath so far would be:

```
arr_Xpath = [ ["/Document-St-5/SDocument/StName"], ["/Document-St-5/SDocument/StCode"], ... ]
```

The `ProdA` node's that are children of node `Items_A` have the following XPath:

```
/Document-St-5/SDocument/ItemList/Items_A/ItemElem/Item_Values/ProdA
```

The `ProdA` node's that are children of node `Items_B` have the following XPath:

```
/Document-St-5/SDocument/ItemList/Items_B/ItemElem/Item_Values/ProdA
```

Then the array of unique XPath of child elements would be (including `ProdB` node's XPath):

```
arr_Xpath = [ "/Document-St-5/SDocument/StName", 
        "/Document-St-5/SDocument/StCode", 
        "/Document-St-5/SDocument/ItemList/Items_A/ItemElem/Item_Values/ProdA", 
        "/Document-St-5/SDocument/ItemList/Items_A/ItemElem/Item_Values/ProdB",
        "/Document-St-5/SDocument/ItemList/Items_B/ItemElem/Item_Values/ProdA",
                  "/Document-St-5/SDocument/ItemList/Items_B/ItemElem/Item_Values/ProdB" ]
```

I think, knowing first the unique XPaths, it would be possible to use `doc.xpath("..")` to get values of each child element and group them 
if it has more than one occurence. So, the final array I'd like to get is:

```
arr_Values = [ ["WERLJ01"], ["MEKLD"],["2","9"],["8","3"],["1"],["17"]]
```

Where:

- `arr_Values[0]` is the array that contains `StName` values
- `arr_Values[1]` is the array that contains `StCode` values
- `arr_Values[2]` is the array that contains the values of all the `ProdA` node's children of `Items_A`.
- `arr_Values[3]` is the array that contains the values of all the `ProdB` node's children of `Items_A`.
- `arr_Values[4]` is the array that contains the values of all the `ProdA` node's children of `Items_B`.
- `arr_Values[5]` is the array that contains the values of all the `ProdB` node's children of `Items_B`.

An XML example is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Document-St-5>
  <SDocument>
    <StName>WERLJ01</StName>
    <StCode>MEKLD</StCode>
  <ItemList>
    <Items_A>
      <ItemElem>
        <Item_Values>
          <ProdA>2</ProdA>
          <ProdB>8</ProdB>
        </Item_Values>
      </ItemElem>        
    </Items_A>
    <Items_A>
      <ItemElem>
        <Item_Values>
          <ProdA>9</ProdA>
          <ProdB>3</ProdB>
        </Item_Values>
      </ItemElem>        
    </Items_A>       
    <Items_B>
      <ItemElem>
        <Item_Values>
          <ProdA>1</ProdA>
          <ProdB>17</ProdB>
        </Item_Values>
      </ItemElem>
    </Items_B>
  </ItemList>
  </SDocument>
</Document-St-5>
```

**Update 2:**

Hello the Tin Man, it works! What does it mean the "%w" and "%w[element1 element2]"? Does the form %w[...] accept more than 2 elements?

I newbie to Nokogiri, I only mention Xpath since the XML have more than 200 unique child nodes (unique Xpath's), then do you suggest me to use the same technique with CSS for all child nodes or is there a way to process the XML and do the same (group in array the elements with same name and that have same Xpath) without knowing the name of the child nodes? I'd like to know the way you suggest me.

Thanks again

Comment: What difference does it make whether people/answerers use XPaths or CSS as accessors? XPaths, especially as you've shown them, will be less flexible and more verbose. Specifying the full path to a node will also make your code more fragile; A change to the XML structure will break your app. Instead, use landmarks to locate the data you want.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(<<EOT)
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Document-St-5>
  <SDocument>
    <ItemList>
      <Items_A>
        <ItemElem>
          <Item_Values>
            <ProdA>2</ProdA>
            <ProdB>8</ProdB>
          </Item_Values>
        </ItemElem>        
      </Items_A>
      <Items_B>
        <ItemElem>
          <Item_Values>
            <ProdA>8</ProdA>
            <ProdB>9</ProdB>
          </Item_Values>
        </ItemElem>
      </Items_B>
    </ItemList>
  </SDocument>
</Document-St-5>
EOT

data = doc.search('SDocument').map{ |node| 
  %w[ProdA ProdB].map{ |n| node.search(n).map(&:text) }
}


data # => [[["2", "8"], ["8", "9"]]]
```

It results in a bit deeper nesting than you want but it's close.

A little different way, perhaps more easily understood, is:

```
data = doc.search('SDocument').map{ |node| 
  %w[A B].map{ |ab|
    node.at("Items_#{ ab }").search('ProdA, ProdB').map(&:text)
  }
}
```

The reason the nesting is one-level deeper than you specified is, I'm assuming there will be multiple `<SDocument>` tags in the XML. If there won't be, then the code can be modified a bit to return the array as you're asking:

```
data = doc.search('Items_A, Items_B').map{ |node| 
  node.search('ProdA, ProdB').map(&:text)
}

data # => [["2", "8"], ["8", "9"]]
```

Notice I'm using CSS selectors, to make it easy to specify I want the code to look at two different nodes, both for `Items_A` and `Items_B`, and `ProdA` and `ProdB`.

---

Update after the question completely changed:

Here's the set-up:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(<<EOT)
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Document-St-5>
  <SDocument>
    <StName>WERLJ01</StName>
    <StCode>MEKLD</StCode>
  <ItemList>
    <Items_A>
      <ItemElem>
        <Item_Values>
          <ProdA>2</ProdA>
          <ProdB>8</ProdB>
        </Item_Values>
      </ItemElem>        
    </Items_A>
    <Items_A>
      <ItemElem>
        <Item_Values>
          <ProdA>9</ProdA>
          <ProdB>3</ProdB>
        </Item_Values>
      </ItemElem>        
    </Items_A>       
    <Items_B>
      <ItemElem>
        <Item_Values>
          <ProdA>1</ProdA>
          <ProdB>17</ProdB>
        </Item_Values>
      </ItemElem>
    </Items_B>
  </ItemList>
  </SDocument>
</Document-St-5>  
EOT
```

Here's the code:

```
data = %w[StName StCode].map{ |n| [doc.at(n).text] }
%w[ProdA ProdB].each do |prod|
  data << doc.search('Items_A').map{ |item| item.at(prod).text }
end
%w[ProdA ProdB].each do |prod|
  data << [doc.at("Items_B #{prod}").text]
end
```

Here's what was captured:

```
data # => [["WERLJ01"], ["MEKLD"], ["2", "9"], ["8", "3"], ["1"], ["17"]]
```

Comment: Hello the Tin Man, thanks for the answer and explanations shared. Please see question below "Update...", I've updated it, becuse my first explanation was inexact, I hope you can point me in rigth direction to make it possible. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's *really* important that your question be accurate when asked. Changing it later, either by supplying different source data, or different requirements, can completely alter the answers, resulting in a Q&A page that is confusing to others when they search for the same question. In addition it'll make it even harder for you to get the answer you want.

Comment: Yes, it was an error, I updated if acceptable. If not I'm not sure if it is better to open a new question?.

Comment: Hello the Tin Man, it works! What does it mean the "%w" and "%w[element1 element2]"? Does the form %w[...] accept more than 2 elements?

Comment: Since the XML have more than 200 unique child nodes (unique Xpath's) do you suggest me to use the same technique with CSS or is there a way to process the XML and do the same (group in array the elements with same name  and that have same Xpath) without knowing the name of the child nodes? I'd like to know the way you suggest me. Thanks again

Comment: `%w[...]` is explained in all basic Ruby tutorials and books. It's just another way of creating an array. As for how to handle your XML, again, locate your landmarks, nodes you can use to identify where your target data is, find those, then use a selector to grab the individual data nodes. It's rarely necessary to hard-code your selectors, and usually you can let the libxml parser search the DOM quickly to find what you want. That's all my examples do.

Comment: Thank you the Tin Man for help. I'll try follow yor examples and suggestions. I was thinking in get values without hard-code any node reference, like without know the XML structure, but it much more complicated I think. Thanks again

Comment: You have to have some idea of the XML structure. At a minimum you need to know the name of the node(s) you want, and often you have to use a node above, below, or beside the one you actually want, in order to access the data you want, so there is no hard and fast rule, or simple way of getting there. Every XML and HTML structure is different, so download it, open it in a text editor, and nose around until you locate what you're looking for, then start coding.